# How do I pass Rails' cycle() an array of values to cycle through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like the [cycle](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-cycle) method to take an array of values which I compile on the fly, but it seems to be interpreting it not as I'd have hoped.

(In this example it's a static array, but I want it to work so that I can use arrays that are constructed variably)

```
- some_array = ['one', 'two', 'three']
- colors.each do |color|
  %a{ :name => color, :class => "#{cycle(some_array)}" }
```

That applies this as a class to each element:

```
"three"] "two", ["one",
```

...looks as though it's calling `to_s` on the array or something.

How am I supposed to be doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cycle` takes multiple arguments and cycles through them. You're passing a *single* argument, an array.

You can use the splat operator to change the array into these multi arguments:

```
cycle(*some_array)
```

This will act as if you did:

```
cycle("one", "two", "three")
```

Rather than:

```
cycle(["one", "two", "three"])
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks so much for taking the time.